# Query nested fields with elasticsearch in grails

Tags: grails, elasticsearch, grails-orm, elasticsearch-plugin

I'm new to `elasticseach` and I'm having some issues to add filters to my queries.

My domain classes are like this:

```
Class A {
    String name
    A_Status status

    static searchable =  {
        status component: true
    }
}

Class AImpl extends A {

}

Class A_Status {
    String name
    static searchable = { 
        root : false
        only = 'name'
    }
}
```

On my controller the query I'm doing is:

```
def res = elasticSearchService.search()
{
    bool {
        must {
            term("status.name": "ACTIVE")
        }
    }
 }
```

I tried changing the `searchable` field to `AImpl` or putting `"searchable = true"`, but had the same results, the query is empty always and it should get 4 results.

Another odd thing I found is that doing the uri search gives me the expected result, but the body query didn't.

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/com.sisconline.entities/_search?q=status.name=ACTIVE'
```

This has 4 hits.

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/com.sisconline.entities/_search' -d '{
"query" : {
      "term":{ "status.name":"ACTIVE"}
      }
}'
```

This gets 0 hits.

I'm using `Grails 2.3.4` and `elasticsearch plugin 0.0.3.5`.

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to solve problem by doing :

```
must { 
  nested { 
     path = "status" 
     query { 
         bool { 
            must { 
               term("status.name": "active") } 
            } 
         } 
     } 
}
```

Hope it helps others.

Comment: Did you try to search using your domains?
I have the similar mappings (even practically the same) and faced with the problem, 
that when I try to search by AImpl, f.e 
 `AImpl.search("${query}")` there is an exception in tomcat

`ERROR unmarshall.DomainClassUnmarshaller  - Error unmarshalling Class AImpl with id ...
Message: Property AImpl.status is not mapped as [component], but broken search hit found. `

Also, if I try to search by superclass, like
  `A.search("${query}")` 

I receive no results, it seems that nothing was indexed for A.

Comment: @JulyAntonicheva From what I've seen so far the framework indexes the child classes not the parent, so if you try to search by your parent class you won't get any results. In fact I had to write the searchable closure in all my child classes, maybe there is a configuration parameter I didn't see. I didn't query using my domain because I wanted all the possible results.

Comment: @JulyAntonicheva Regarding the error you are getting, it's probably that you didn't specify your attribute as a component, in my example was "status component: true" or you have changed your mappings and didn't clean your index to rebuild it.